# Most efficient way to clean and reorder two arrays based on their matching selected columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, intersection

say we have array1 and array2 both of which are two dimensional, and may have non-unique rows, and different number of rows.

My final goal is to have a cleaned version of the two arrays with the same shape, and ordered such that for each row index the values in column 2,3, and 4 are the same.

In below I describe a possible sequence to achieve this final goal which I am wondering about the most efficient way for in using numpy.

1_if there are rows in array1 with similar values in column 2,3,4, remove them.

2_if there are rows in array2 with similar values in column 2,3,4, remove them.

So based on those columns, both arrays will have unique rows.

3_then I want to remove rows which in both arrays that do not have a matching row in the other array in terms of column 2,3,4.

So both arrays should have the same length now.

4_Then I want to reorder array1 so that with the same indecies array2 has the same values in column 2,3,4.

-------------edit: numerical example:

```
array1 = array([1,4,3, 64356,5435,434],
               [11,46,3, 7356,585,74],
               [51,406,3, 769,5435,24],
               [12,45,5, 656,135,134],
               [112,475,5, 656,1385,134],
               [13,46,  5, 656,1385,19]])


array2 = array([15,44,  5, 656, 1385, 434],
               [165,644,5, 656, 1385, 48],
               [151,436,3, 356, 285,74],
               [521,406,5, 656, 135,24],
               [152,445,54, 56,635,134],
               [1812,757,542, 546,185,1834],
               [72,77,142, 66,65,64],
               [72,727,12, 16,55,634]])

array1_final = array([112,475,5, 656,1385,134],
                     [12,45,  5, 656,135,134]
                ])

array2_final = array([15,44,  5,  656,1385,434],
                     [521,406,5, 656,135,24]
                ])
```

although array2[0] and array2[1] both have a match array1[4] in terms of their 2,3,4 columns, only one of them is kept in the final array2. Similarly  , array1[5] was dropped. The final arrays are in the same order in terms of matching 2,3,4 columns.
The rest are dropped because they don't have a matching counterpart in the other array in terms of 2,3,4 columns.

Comment: Some real data with expected results would be helpful here.

Comment: @MBeale done.:)

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer, although admittedly there may be a better one out there.

```
#find the unique rows
array1_v,array_i = np.unique(array1[:,[2,3,4]], axis=0, return_index=True)
array2_v,array2_i = np.unique(array2[:,[2,3,4]], axis=0, return_index=True)

#find if the unique rows exist in the other array
array1_in_array2 = [row.tolist() in array2_v.tolist() for row in array1_v] array2_in_array1 = [row.tolist() in array1_v.tolist() for row in array2_v]
array2_in_array1 = [row.tolist() in array1_v.tolist() for row in array2_v] array2_in_array1 = [row.tolist() in array1_v.tolist() for row in array2_v]

#final results
array1_final = array1[array1_i[array1_in_array2]]
array2_final = array2[array2_i[array2_in_array1]]
>>> array1_final
array([[  12,   45,    5,  656,  135,  134],
       [ 112,  475,    5,  656, 1385,  134]])
```